# Stop-and-copy garbage collection with more than two heap regions?

Tags: memory, garbage-collection

Are there implementations of stop-and-copy garbage collection with more than two heap regions?

If that sounds odd, consider a mutation in a biological organism using stop and copy that would introduce a third, fourth, ... region in the organism's heap. One could then study what effect that would have on the organism and if such a mutation would help its genes spread.

Comment: sorry, but this sounds very abstract. I mean _biological organism_ and _garbage collection_ in the same question? can you provide more details may be?

Comment: It’s not as weird as it sounds. Organisms process information. That means they compute. And garbage collection is such an essential tool for basically any program with state that biological evolution must have bestowed organisms with it pretty soon.

Comment: The misnomer “garbage collection” has led to many wrong analogies, but the idea of a *copying collector* happening in the real world, is very interesting. But I don’t know how it shall help understanding the first sentence. Depending on how you define “heap region”, this is just state of the art, nothing odd about it. It doesn’t work like 1969’s semi-space collector anymore.